# ffmpeg - Invalid report file level (windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg

`ffmpeg` is giving me an error and I couldn't get much help googling it, besides a [thread on ffmpeg mailing list](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2014-June/022084.html) dated 5 years ago which doesn't address the exact same problem.

No matter which [ffmpeg version or build for windows](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) I use, the error is always:

> ```
> c:\>ffmpeg.exe
> Invalid report file level
> ```

I've been using `ffmpeg` on the same computer for years and I've no idea where the problem started and how to debug it. Any help is welcome.

---

**Notes:**

1. No antivirus is running
2. `ffmpeg.exe` is on windows `path`
3. I've tried installing `ffmpeg` with `choco install
   ffmpeg` but it reports the same error.

Comment: Try `set FFREPORT=`

Comment: @Gyan `set FFREPORT=` solved the problem, can you please post an answer so I can accept it as the correct answer? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the environment variable `FFREPORT` is set, `ffmpeg` will parse it to set `loglevel` for the verbosity of the log report and also its location. What you've encountered is a parse failure of that system variable.

So, either unset it using `set FFREPORT=` or set it to a different string. See `-report` under https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Generic-options